# Narrative webpage: translateX with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a function like here:
https://highline.huffingtonpost.com/articles/en/poor-millennials/

There is a `.horizontal-scroll` div. The horizontal scrolling works with mouse wheel. I need something like this as jQuery code.

Who can help me? I would be soooo thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

Example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

Code: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

```
$(function() {
  $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
  event.preventDefault();
  });
})

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

One More Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ye259/4/